# "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform." on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, microsoft-data-sqlclient

I just started getting this error today on my Linux system, building a `net6` solution on Rider - It builds but won't run. I've tried upgrading my version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` from nuget but that's made no difference. This was working fine last week.

There are a couple of things I've done that may have broken it - I got mono working over the weekend to try and get some legacy `NETFramework` code building for another project, for one. The other was a global update of ef tools `dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef` as I had the 5.x tools version installed.

My OS has multiple runtimes installed...

```
dotnet --list-runtimes                                                                                                                                               
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.13 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The app builds to target 6.0.

I'm a bit lost as to where to start trying to find problems - I#ve read about the `netstandard2.0` version of this library being a kind of breaking stub, but the Assembly Explorer in Rider tells me that the version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in my `bin` directory is `net6`. I'm not sure what I should be seeing in the `runtimes` directory in here - I have a `unix` runtime shown there but NOT a linux specific runtime - Is this a red herring or am I on to something?

I've reverted the dotnet-ef tool by uninstalling it and running `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.0` - This hasn't helped at all.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1643#issuecomment-1265104713

Comment: Maybe - I feel some uninstalls may be needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to not install dotnet from the arch or AUR repositories at all.
Instead use the script provided by Microsoft. This installs the original builds.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

I created this wrapper script which I use any time I need to install a machine:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# This script installs specified versions of .NET Core and the latest LTS

# Function to install a specific .NET Core version
install_dotnet_version() {
    local version="$1"
    echo "Installing .NET Core version $version..."
    curl --silent --show-error --location https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh \
        | sudo bash /dev/stdin -c "$version" --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
}

# Install .NET Core versions
install_dotnet_version 3.1
install_dotnet_version LTS
install_dotnet_version 7.0

# Create a symlink to dotnet executable, if not present
if [ ! -f /usr/bin/dotnet ]; then
    sudo ln -sf /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet
fi
```

Comment: This is the way I went in the end too - The script is a nice addition here.

Comment: You're 99.9% right about this `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` Some bug within default repo of my Almalinux build. As, tried with your script. It worked instantly :)

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: I think this is a bug in the .NET builds of Manjaro Linux. When you downloaded Microsoft's builds of .NET, it didn't have this bug and worked correctly.

---

This is what the OS says about itself:

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Manjaro Linux"
PRETTY_NAME="Manjaro Linux"
ID=manjaro
ID_LIKE=arch
BUILD_ID=rolling
ANSI_COLOR="32;1;24;144;200"
HOME_URL="https://manjaro.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://wiki.manjaro.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forum.manjaro.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://docs.manjaro.org/reporting-bugs/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://manjaro.org/privacy-policy/"
LOGO=manjarolinux
```

And this is what .NET thinks about your OS:

```
sh-5.1# dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.113
 Commit:    4a23b50f97

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     manjaro
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.113/
...
```

Do you see how confused .NET is about whether this is Arch Linux or Manjaro?

.NET has a fallback graph that tells it which assets from another OS it can use:

```
# jq '.runtimes' /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.13/Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json
{ 
  "arch-x64": [
    "arch",
    "linux-x64",
    "linux",
    "unix-x64",
    "unix",
    "any",
    "base"
  ]
}
```

But that only contains `arch-x64` (that is, Arch Linux), not `manjaro-x64`.

If you try and build/run your application with the environment variable `COREHOST_TRACE`, you can see output like this:

```
HostRID is manjaro-x64
Falling back to base HostRID: linux-x64
```

So it finally decides this OS is Manjaro, but then has no idea that Manjaro is compatible with everything listed in the fallback graph above. It just falls back to Linux.

Unfortunately, `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is built for either Windows (`windows`) or for Unix (`unix`). .NET can't find a `linux` variant. It finally uses the fallback version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll`, one that just prints errors instead of doing anything useful.

Comment: I did consider whether to try using the AUR packages instead to see if I had better luck with those but as the `dotnet-install` script seems to be happy enough I got to "it's working, just leave it!" mode. The manjaro packages definitely seem awry.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue was, in part, related to having 2 6.x framework versions installed, or with `6.0.13` - I'd tried installing the 6.x packages from the Manjaro repositories over the weekend to replace the script installs.

Dani's comment above pointed me in the right direction (https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1643#issuecomment-1265104713) - There's something odd going on here.

I removed them all and installed again using the `.dotnet-install.sh` script - that just did nothing, so I copied the 6.0.0 install from a backup folder (`mv .old` FTW) and it all fell into place again.

Whether this is an issue with `6.0.13` or with having multiples I'm not sure.

Comment: Glad to know my info was useful :)

Answer (score -1):

Try typing "dotnet --info" in terminal.
Then take your target OS and add it to your c# cs.proj files...

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>ubuntu.22.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

For me. Works for me! The program is loading the wrong DLL, as there are multiple for different platforms. This way, your specifically tell c# which dll to load.

I don't know if this is the best solution. I have spent a few hours researching, and I tried this. It works for me. Previously I tried just using "Linux x64", but it didn't work. So try to be as specific as you can, and use dotnet --info

Comment: This will work for local development, in theory, but that breaks the code on other operating systems so it's not cross-platform anymore really - It's a valid workaround, but not one you want checked into source control with a team.