# dotnet ef database update - System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to migrate my database using Entity Framework Core, but I got this error. I am using .NET Core 7 and all my dependencies are up to date.

It seems like there is a problem with `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, but I don't know how to fix it because the error is not coming from my code but the script that runs the migration update

```
dotnet ef database update

Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime giveUp)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

This is my `.csproj` :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>2f7cbad2-b9a5-49ce-ac90-3ec6f5ce8200</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.10">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="MinimalApis.Extensions" Version="0.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why does your title say "System.Data.SqlClient" if you're using "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"?

Comment: What platform? Whether the error message is legitimate or not, if it tells you that something is not supported on the this platform, it should be obvious that what this platform is is relevant.

Comment: I am using Arch Linux currently

Comment: oops sorry, the title was a mistake

Comment: Linux for development or the database or both?

Comment: the database are running locally in linux, so the development is also on linux

Comment: You may find something relevant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283854/system-platformnotsupportedexception-microsoft-data-sqlclient-is-not-supported).